# About node.js with mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using node.js with mysql database.

I'm using the config like this:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var client = mysql.createConnection({
     host: 'localhost',
     user: 'root',
     password: 'java1234',
     port: '3306',
     database: 'sample'
});
```

and then I get these error messages:

> Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>       at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
>       at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:124:18)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:278:23)
>       at Parser.write (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
>       at Protocol.write (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
>       at Socket. (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:91:28)
>       at Socket. (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
>       --------------------
>       at Protocol._enqueue (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
>       at Protocol.handshake (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
>       at Connection.connect (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:118:18)
>       at Connection._implyConnect (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:453:10)
>       at Connection.query (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:8)
>       at C:\node\test11_users\routes\users.js:26:10
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\node\test11_users\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

but I can't solve this problem.
thanks for your explain easily.

Comment: It basically means your credentials are not correct. Are you able to access mySQL outside?

Comment: How can I access mysql outside? Do you mean Workbench?

Comment: yes or phpadmin anything will do. try logging in with the creds above.

Comment: I can access mysql with Workbench surly. but only node.js not working

Comment: go to users and privileges page in work bench and check the configuration for `root` over there.

Comment: I just checked out you said. it already has been checked all of checkbox in Administrative roles and Global Privileges. (T.T)

Comment: Try creating a new one over there and replace the creds above.

Answer (score -1):

Remove port from connection options and try

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'java1234',
  database : 'sample'
});
```

`connection.connect();`